# What does "./" (dot slash) refer to in terms of an HTML file path location?

Tags: javascript, html, path

I know `../` means go up a path, but what does `./` mean exactly?

I was recently going through a tutorial and it seems to be referring to just a file in the same location, so is it necessary at all? Can I just not use it if that's all it's doing?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

`./` is the the folder that the *working* file is in:

So in `/index.htm` `./` is the root directory
but in `/css/style.css` `./` is the css folder.

This is important to remember because if you move CSS from `/index.htm` to `/css/style.css` the path will change.

Comment: How does this answer the question? Apparently, Simon Suh understands that ./ refers to the same location where the referring file is. The main part of the question then is: "Why to use it and is it necessary at all?". The only reason to prefer the syntax of "./file" instead of "file" I was able to find is that ./ means current folder and ONLY the current folder. So if there is some kind of tool/compiler/etc that searches for the file, then './file' will search ONLY in current folder, whereas 'file' will search wherever the tool is configured to search (e.g. root, current folder, etc.)

Comment: So whats the difference between `./abc.htm` and just `abc.htm`?

Comment: @Teemoh They're the same in JS, HTML and CSS. The "./" is a old programing convention that carried over into these newer languages. In other circumstance they could mean different things. eg. if a "path" is set in an OS abc.exe could be a file and ./abc.exe might not.

Comment: @MarcelToth you really should post this as an answer!

Comment: what does "scripts/**/*.js" means? Is it telling us to pick all "js" files under scripts folder?

Comment: I think its important to understand that using "./" in a file path then moving the file to a new folder never changes the path because "./" always resolves to a file's current folder. That is why its use is redundant in web path systems.

Comment: In Typescript when importing a file you must use "./path/to/file" if the file's path is in the current working directory.

Answer (score 389):

`/` means the root of the current drive;

`./` means the current directory;

`../` means the parent of the current directory.

Comment: Does the "header("Location: ../");" redirect to the parent directory?

Comment: how is ./index.html different from just index.html?

Comment: I have a piece of code from a template, it contains `././` what does this mean?

Comment: @AaronFranke Translated to english, that says something to the effect of "This directory, this directory" so it is equivalent to `./` ("This directory"), `./././` ("This directory, this directory, this directory"), `././././` and so on.

Answer (score 184):

You can use the following list as quick reference:

```
   /   = Root directory
   .   = This location
   ..  = Up a directory
   ./  = Current directory
   ../ = Parent of current directory
   ../../ = Two directories backwards
```

Useful article:
https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/

Comment: What difference between "This location" and "Current directory" ? Thank you.

Comment: @WebBrother, As it turned out ./ works only in non-strict doctype mode, while . works in both modes, here is a link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296873/basic-html-how-to-set-relative-path-to-current-folder

Comment: Thank you. This clear explanation just solved a problem so basic I was embarrassed to ask out loud.

Answer (score 62):

```
.  = This location
.. = Up a directory
```

So, `./foo.html` is just `foo.html`. And it is optional, but may have relevance if a script generated the path (relevance to the *script* that is, not how the reference works).

Answer (score 45):

Yes, `./` means the current working directory.  You can just reference the file directly by name, without it.

Answer (score 23):

A fast and small recap about **paths**

### Absolute paths

`http://website.com/assets/image.jpg`
IF the image is **not on your domain** - go look there for image

---

`//website.com/assets/image.jpg`
image loaded using http or https protocols

---

### Relative paths

(For *internal use* if the image is on the same server)

---

`image.jpg`
**image** in the same place as the document calling the image!

---

`./image.jpg`
Same as above,  **image** in the same place as the document calling the image!

---

`/assets/image.jpg`
**Similar to Absolute Paths, just omitting the protocol and domain name**
Go search my image starting from my root folder `/`, than into `assets/`

---

`assets/image.jpg`
this time **assets** is in the same place as the document, so go into **assets** for the image

---

`../assets/image.jpg`
From where the document is, go **one** folder **back** `../` and go into `assets`

---

`../../image.jpg`
go **two** folders **back**, there's my image!

---

`../../assets/image.jpg`
go **two** folders **back** `../../` *and than go into* `assets`

Comment: Is there a way to say "go to the ultimate root and then follow this path" without using the domain name (ie, if you need the site to work in a staging environment)? Or do you just have to do something like ../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../images/image.jpg and hope that covers every possible scenario?

Comment: @Mark if I got your question right, you need to "go back (indefinite times) till root, then enter `images`. See Relative paths and the third example `/images/image. jpg`

Answer (score 13):

You are correct that you can omit it. It's useful only for clarity. There is no functional difference between it being there and not being there.

Comment: `It's useful only for clarity.` Or confusion, in OP's case - and mine. :)

Comment: You cannot omit it when you import javascript file in html5. For example if u have a folder js and an index.html file in one directory:The <script src="./js/main.js"></script> declared in html 5 is correct but if you omit the '.' notation, it won't load the file.

Comment: @MaXi32 - In your example, `<script src="js/main.js"></script>` will load the file in HTML5 as well as `./js/main.js`

Answer (score 3):

For example css files are in folder named `CSS` and html files are in folder `HTML`, and both these are in folder named `XYZ` means we refer css files in html as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./../CSS/style.css" />
```

Here `..` moves up to `HTML`
and `.` refers to the current directory `XYZ`

---by this logic you would just reference as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css" />
```

Comment: The second reference `"CSS/style.css"` did not work for me, maybe you meant `"../CSS/style.css"`?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah `./` means the directory you're currently in.

Comment: This is a bit misleading.  `./thisfile.txt` is not always equivalent to `/thisfile.txt`.  It is entirely dependent on what directory the code is executing in.

Comment: @JonathanNewmuis is right ./thisfile.txt is not explicitly /thisfile.txt

Comment: so if the code executes in a different place, `./` will refer to the original place?

Answer (score 1):

Do NOT use `./` as a web path when working directly with either `CSS`, `HTML`, or Web paths online! I explain why and what it is below...

**TRUE WEB PATHS YOU SHOULD ALWAYS USE**

`../siblingfolder/file.html` is a web path that starts from the folder you are in, **goes up** one parent folder (../), goes down into a new folder called "siblingfolder" and to "file.html" inside it. This is a type of **relative path** in the web world.

`childfolder/file.html` is another kind of web path that starts from the folder you are in and **goes down** to "childfolder" and "file.html" inside it. This is also as a **relative path**.

`/subrootfolder/file.html` is a web path that starts from the *web root* of your website and **goes down from the web root** into "subrootfolder" as an **absolute path**. Note: This path has the added advantage in that it *works from any file and folder location on the server*.

`http://somewebsite.com/subrootfolder/file.html` is another web path which works exactly the same as the ones above, but requires your *web domain* in the path. It still works but is very limiting because the web domain is hard-coded into the path. Some call this a **fully qualified web path**, which has some uses. The web browser also resolves most file paths to this address or an IP version of it.

**AWKWARD AND RARELY USED PATHS**

`.` is a shorthand for the current location or file context and is used in Linux and Unix to execute a compiled program in the current directory. That is why you don't see this used in Web Development much except by open source, non-Windows frameworks like **Google Angular** which was written by people stuck on open source platforms.

`./` also resolves to the current directory and is atypical in Web but supported as a path in some open source frameworks. Because it resolves the same as *no path* to the current file directory its not used. Example: **./image.jpg = image.jpg**. Even though it is used by software to identify a current folder location, because it is identical to the current software path or file location, it is the same as no path so redundant. Again, this is a relic of Unix operating systems that need path resolutions like this to run executables and resolve paths for security reasons. Its not a typical web path. That is why this syntax is redundant in HTML and web technologies.

`//somewebsite.com/folder/folder/file.html` this is a form of a fully qualified web URL resolution format. "//" tells the web browser to determine the fully qualified web URL/URI at runtime and concatenate the right http protocol onto the front of your path as so: `https://mywebsite.com/folder/folder/file.html`. It allows the browser to query one of many web domains and determine the most secure location or protocol to use: Either "http" or "https" as the most favorable and secure prefix. This is rarely used in most internal web paths but likely found in `link` *href attribute* paths in newer HTML5 elements and used when adding links to resources that may resolve to unknown dynamic secure socket layer connections at runtime that change.

**PATH EQUIVALENTS**

`folder = /folder` a *relative path* is the same as an *absolute path* in this case if the file accessing this child "folder" is located under the web root directory. Both paths would work the same for them.

`../folder = /folder` a relative path going up to a parent folder then down to "folder" is the same as the absolute path if the file accessing this path again is in the web root directory.

`./folder = folder` both relative paths start with the files current folder and point to the child "folder" under them no matter where these folders are located, so are the same. "./" is therefore redundant.

`./file.html = file.html` both relative paths point to the current folder and then to a "file.html" inside that folder. This means use of "./" is redundant.

`./ = {no path}` an empty path is the same as `./` in the web world so redundant again.

`./ = /` only true again if the file is under the web root folder. Again this means "./" is redundant.

**MY WEB PATH RECOMMENDATIONS**

ALWAYS use **Absolute Paths** ("/myfolder/myfile") whenever possible as they will always work from any file location in the web project, add no confusion to developers, moving files with absolute paths will not change paths, and they are easy to maintain and manage. The only drawback to absolute paths is if you move the files or folders being pathed to new locations (example: You move an image or CSS folder of files to a new location later in the project). That is why I recommend you manage paths via server-side virtual paths, application paths, or server-generated variables so you can change absolute paths dynamically as you move things around.

ALWAYS use **Relative Web Paths** ("../myfile") as a *secondary option*. These are a must for CSS file paths, CSS imported files, or font paths within CSS files. They should only be used if your web application is designed with many parallel applications running side-by-side under one domain, and have nested and heavily dependent resource files running inside them that must be separated. In that one case, you will often move these applications as one module deeper into the application making relative pathing more valuable. You will determine paths relative to the source files in that case and not relative to the web domain via absolute paths. As above, I would still manage paths via server-side or virtual application generated paths. This makes paths extremely simple, robust, and easy to dynamically update on the fly via server variables rather than inside scripts and dependencies which constantly evolve.

Here is PROOF that these UNIX "dot" paths fail on the web and why you should avoid them...

```
// IMAGE PATH JAVASCRIPT ERRORS
// These paths return broken image icons in browsers when using
// these unconventional UNIX local dot path conventions on the Web:
<img id="image1" src="./images/image1.png" />
<img id="image2" src="/images/.image2.png" />
```

NEVER use the other paths listed unless forced to by atypical, 3rd party, proprietary software conventions that use substandard pathing solutions that add confusion and added maintenance. :(

Answer (score 0):

> ./  = Current directory

This is correct but as i figured out from some templates that i worked on before, the purpose of this identification is to remind the developer that the file to be accessed is not actually in the same directory as the HTML file being worked. Yes, I know it sounds weird.

Developers who use such definitions usually put a `<base href="">` tag at the beginning of the HEAD block of the HTML page. Double quotes also indicate the directory they want to reach, so they don't have to define phrases like "../images" to access all of the image files that are not in the same directory as the HTML.

For example,

> ```
> /main
>
> / /assets
>
> / / /css
> / / /images
>
> / / / /logo.png
>
> / /html
>
> / / /demo
>
> / / / /index.html
>
> / /plugins
> ```

every time you want to access the files in the images folder from the index.html file on a website with a directory structure like above, you need to use the `src="../../assets/images"` path. If you specify `<base href="../../assets">` instead, you can now just use `"images/" or "./images"`. Of course, remember, in this case, you will need to specify the file locations accordingly, as other page links will also be based on that `<base>` tag. So it's up to you whether you need to use it or not.

I did not wrote this to find the correct answer. This is my experience about the "./" usage so i wanted to share it. I hope it could help anybody.

Answer (score -2):

In reference to the quick reference list, specifically you can use the following :

\.\ Root Directory + Current directory (Drive Letter)