# What does the decimal in the relative link path do?

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “./” (dot slash) refer to in terms of an HTML file path location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591240/what-does-dot-slash-refer-to-in-terms-of-an-html-file-path-location)

What is the purpose of the decimal in the following, widely used reference to an external css sheet. Thanks in advance.

**Why the decimal? here "./css"?**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: It's not a "decimal", it's a "dot".

Comment: Actually, it's a period. A dot is something you get on your shirt when you touch it with the tip of a pen.

Comment: Or a full stop in UK / Australian English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.` refers to the current folder. It doesn't really do anything, it's sort of a no-op.

Comment: This is correct, I often use them just because I think it makes it a bit clearer it's a relative path instead of just css/style.css