# how to set background-image

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net MVC.
In my application,To set the background image,I have implemented like,

```
 background-image:url("../../Images/Home/Logo.png");
```

When I debug this,background image is displaying ,when I deploy it to the server,It is not displaying .
If I implement like

```
background-image:url("Images/Home/Logo.png");
```

background-image is displaying after deploying in the server but in my local it is not displaying,what is the solution for this?

Comment: Try with absolute path...

Comment: @SudipPal Do you means change everytime when do something in dev or production environment or make a configuration variable to handle this issue.

Comment: @charan You can put the url relative to imageurl and your current file (which you are edit). This trick will work on both server and production.

Comment: @F1beta Yes, here absolute path means, domain name should come from variable and as per my knowledge, I think everyone should use different configuration file for different application environment.

Comment: @SudipPal as Aliriza's answer their is no way to do dynamic thing in css file. You need to find/Replace everytime when you upload the css file on server. Yes, If you write css inside masterpage or cshtml aspx kind render-engine then you can do it :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use correct client relative path

```
aspxImgCtrl.ImageUrl = "~/Images/GIF/arrow.png";
```

The ~ operator is recognized by asp.net only for server controls and in server code. You cannot use the ~ operator for client elements.

Try

```
background:url('<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/path/to/img") %>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Place cssImages in same place with css file.  I mean

```
Root
    Content
        Site.css
        Images
            Logo.png
```

And use absolute path like this: `background-image:url("Images/Logo.png");` in Site.css

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem. This can be fixed by placing the image folder inside the same folder where your css files are

> I hope you know the meaning of ***"../"*** [Refer Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591240/what-does-dot-slash-refer-to-in-terms-of-an-html-file-path-location). If you know this
>   you can fix the thing easily.

Comment: In the server it is displaying,but in the local it is not displaying if I implement like "././Images/Home/Logo.png"

Comment: Charan, As I have mentioned place your Image folder inside the css folder and try with out "../" donot use ././