# html base tag not working correctly

Tags: html, base-path

I am using html base tag in head but not working very well.

This is my folder structure.

```
- BaseWebsite (Folder)
- - Root (Folder)
- - default.html
- - css (Folder)
- - js (Folder)
- - image (Folder)
```

in IIS, i create a new web site pointing to `BaseWebsite` and made `Root` an application.

This is my code in `default.html`

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/site.css" />
<script language="javascript" src="js/site.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
<img src="image/site.jpg" />
.
.
.
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the page, css is there with the `href="Root/css/site.css"` but js and image are missing with the src starting `js/site.js` and `image/site.jpg`

So I put this after `<head>`

```
<base href="/Root/" />
```

Now, both js and image are showing but css is not showing as the href becomes `href="/Root/Root/css/site.css"`

Is it normal or how do I solve this? I can solve it by change href of css to `/Root/css/site.css` but there are a lot of places to change.

Comment: End <head> tag in html

Comment: If you are using `<base href="/Root/" />` as base, should you not be doing `../css/` for relative path to the css folder?

Comment: my question is if js and image are working, why css is not working?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In a [`base` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-BASE), the `href` attribute must be an absolute URL, such as `http://www.example.com/foo/bar/`. A URL that begins with `/` (or `.`) is relative.

You need to fix the absolute URL or use some other technique, such as a server-side programming tool or a preprocessor.

Comment: I believe this is incorrect. The base URL __can__ be relative. See [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#frozen-base-url) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base).

Answer (score 0):

i dont know how behaves ISS, but try with dot:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/site.css" />
```

i hope it helps

brief explanation:
"./" starts where default.html is.

long explained here: 
[What does "./" (dot slash) refer to in terms of an HTML file path location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591240/what-does-dot-slash-refer-to-in-terms-of-an-html-file-path-location)

Comment: yes. i know it might work. but my problem is i m unable to update all css links cos they are spreading everywhere..