# IIS Rewrite to NOT rewrite path to JS, CSS, etc. files

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, .htaccess

So I've been struggling with my Angular.js application and IIS rewrite. I have my site sitting in `http://server/jwb/` folder. I have it rewriting to the index.html file in /jwb/ and I have a `<base href="/jwb/">` inside of the index.html. The problem is that when I navigate to `http://server/jwb/parties/12345`, it appears fine when done through angular, but when I hit refresh on the browser I lose the CSS and javascript. I look in the console and they are being rewritten to `http://server/jwb/parties/js/nameoffile.js`, etc. What I want to do is tell IIS rewrite to always see the js, css and img files where they really reside which is at `http://server/jwb/js`, `http://server/jwb/css` and `http://server/jwb/img`, etc.

What is the rewrite rule that will accomplish this for me? Is there a better way than using a rewrite rule?

I currently have this in my web.config:

```
<rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^index\.html" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="None" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
```

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17080595/446594) the `base` attribute should be an absolute URL

Comment: According to [the mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) both relative and absolute paths are allowed. However, some browsers (IE8, and firefox older than 4) don't support relative paths.

Comment: My first thought was "Who SAAAAAYYYZZZZ that?" but I gave it a shot. Of course, the problem persists. The problem is that the js, css and img files are trying to pull from the angular path and not the real path. Interestingly, my angular routing (which was broken) is now working. If I could solve this other issue things would be perfect.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm struggling with the same problem.

Comment: No, right now we have the entire path to the files in our index.html file, but we believe that the IIS rewrite rules are not firing at all. We can see that angular routing takes over when you first hit the site, but upon refresh, IIS should kick in and fails to do so.