# Error - Cannot find module 'config'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have mail configuration code in `all.js`.

Now i am trying to import this in my `mail.js` service, so i imported the `config` module as follows :-

mail.js

```
config = require('config'),
```

all.js

```
mailer: {
        auth: {
            user: "XXXXXXX",
            pass: "abc@123"
        }
    }
```

[image]

Gives me error cannot find module, but the module exists i have checked it.

How to solve this?

Comment: Have you exported the module..? As in did something like Module.Exports.Mailer = {auth : {...}}

Comment: `config.js` exports `all.js` & my code is in `all.js`.

Comment: Try this config = require('config').mailer, if you are exporting a object called mailer, you need to refer to it.

Comment: tried...still giving error cannot find module `config`

Comment: Try using path `require('./config/config');` see [File modules](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules)

Comment: Again error cannot find module `./config/config`

Comment: Is [config](https://npmjs.org/package/config) even installed ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I used the following code & it worked :-

```
config = require('../config/config');
```

Comment: Yeah, you have to use relative path (starting with '../' or './'), otherwise node.js will look into node_modules folder.

Comment: Make sure to know how to differentiate between **../** and **./**.
`.  = This location
    .. = Up a directory`

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591240/what-does-dot-slash-refer-to-in-terms-of-an-html-file-path-location)

Answer (score 5):

This also occurs when you don't have the config package installed. You may just need to install the config package

```
npm i config
```

Answer (score 0):

so you have to modify the path relative to the file you are using process.env not relative to the specified file config.json

eg:

```
node_modules
.gitignore
.env
config.json
folder:
     file.js
```

using config.json in file.js process.env.SECRET_KEY

```
.env: SECRET_KEY=../config.json //because you go out of folder in file.js to get into config.json
```