# CSS Image Path Not Working

Tags: css

After extensive research, I have tried

```
background-image: url("/images/image.jpg");
../../images/image.jpg
../images/image.jpg
/images/image.jpg
./image.jpg
```

And the entire URL. Plus others. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

The path is forward one directory.

This is my CSS:

```
nav {
    background-image: url ("./images/navmenu.jpg");
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    margin:0;
    display:block;
    padding:0;

}
```

Comment: If `"/images/image.jpg"` doesn't work, that means that the picture is not at `"/images/image.jpg"`.

Comment: İs there any warning at console ?

Comment: Where (relative to your web root directory) is your CSS file?  Where (again, relative to your web root directory) is the "images" directory.  If you are not using a CSS file and just inserting the style into the document (aka embedded stylesheet), don't.  It's a bad idea.  Move the styles to a .css file instead, link to it in your pages.  That will maintain more consistency.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "./" (dot slash) refer to in terms of an HTML file path location?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591240/what-does-dot-slash-refer-to-in-terms-of-an-html-file-path-location)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space after `url` and also remove `./` before `images` in the path:

```
background-image: url("images/navmenu.jpg");
```

Comment: Awesome. Combining this answer with the two dots, it worked for me. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

```
nav {
background-image: url ("../images/navmenu.jpg");
width:100%;
height:200px;
margin:0;
display:block;
padding:0;

}
```

use double dots before /images this will work for you.

Comment: When I combined this answer with the one above, it worked. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the page up in chrome, then inspect the nav element then look at the css that your chrome is trying to access (mouse over the url portion in the css styles tab. It should help you identify your issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether folder name is images or Images. Accordingly use the style -

```
background-image: url("images/navmenu.jpg");

or

background-image: url("Images/navmenu.jpg");
```

if it is happening in your website please share the url so that we can find the exact problem.
Thanks