# How to access all the files when using nested includes in php

Tags: php

I am facing some trouble in accessing the file from a folder.

My current scenario is:
I can accces following folders:

- `localhost/testproject/`
- `localhost/testproject/inc`
- `localhost/testproject/news`

And I have two files:

- `localhost/testproject/inc/header.php`
- `localhost/testproject/news/test.php`

In the header.php there are some css files included.
Now the problem is that if I try to include the `header.php` in `test.php` it does not load the css files.

Comment: Comnpressed the Question to clearify

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find that out that I have to create a site url in config file and include all the css and the js files according to that site url.

```
config.php

define("SITE_URL",'http://localhost/testproject/');

header.php

include "config.php";

<link href="<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And that is it :) 
thanks every one for there response.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you have the CSS link in the header.php. The best solution is to change the link from

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style_of_header.css" type="text/css">`

to:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./inc/style_of_header.css" type="text/css">`

The `.` takes you back to the root folder. From there you can specify the folder relative from the root folder.

Comment: This is almost correct.  It should be `href="/inc/style_of_header.css"`; it's a leading slash, not a leading dot, that means "go back up to the site root".

Comment: It appears that the dot means the working directory. Found it here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591240/what-does-dot-slash-refer-to-in-terms-of-an-html-file-path-location)

Comment: As a relative URL, `./inc/whatever` is exactly the same as `inc/whatever`.