# What is the purpose of adding a "." in a path to a file?

Tags: syntax

While looking over documentation of projects, tools etc. I have noticed individuals prepending a period to a file path:

[image: pic from gulp-sprite documentation]

I have tried with and without and it still works, but why do people use the convention?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "./" (dot slash) refer to in terms of an HTML file path location?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591240/what-does-dot-slash-refer-to-in-terms-of-an-html-file-path-location)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the specific environment whether a `.` has a specific meaning. In general `.` stands for *the current directory* (and `..` being the parent directory). If the environment uses a `PATH`-like lookup system, there may well be a difference between `./foo` and `foo`.

The `PATH` is an environment variable in many systems which defines several paths in which files are looked up. E.g. `PATH=/bar:/baz:.`. This mean, when you try to refer to file `foo`, this will be looked up as `/bar/foo`, `/baz/foo` and `./foo`, the first one to match wins.

As such, the difference *can* be important *if* the system uses such a relative lookup. I'm not clear on whether gulp does specifically. If it doesn't, it's relatively redundant to use `.`.