# Font problems with IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, font-face

I'm having problems during webdevelopment for IE8. The website should support IE8. Font will not shown correctly.

I use the following code:

```
@font-face {  
  font-family: 'MyFont';
  src: url('./fonts/myfont/eot/Myfont.eot');
  src: url('./fonts/myfont/eot/Myfont.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
   url('./fonts/myfont/woff/Myfont.woff') format('woff'),
   url('fonts/myfont/ttf/Myfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
   url('./fonts/myfont/svg/Myfont.svg#webfont') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

What can I do that the font will be shown correctly?.

Thx for your help.

Comment: does the font work in other browsers? for your iefix try this: `url('./fonts/myfont/eot/Myfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype')`

Comment: how the font is not shown correctly? please, could you provide a better description of the problem?

Comment: The fonts  work on other browsers (Chrome, Firefox) include IE9 but not in IE8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like you have formatted it properly

if your linking outside of the tree the you should have `../` not `./`.

Also you were missing the trailing from `truetype`.

And `eot` should be `embedded-opentype`

```css
@font-face {  
  font-family: 'MyFont';
  src: url('../fonts/myfont/eot/Myfont.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/myfont/eot/Myfont.eot?iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
   url('../fonts/myfont/woff/Myfont.woff') format('woff'),
   url('../fonts/myfont/ttf/Myfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
   url('../fonts/myfont/svg/Myfont.svg#webfont') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: depends if the font folder is in the same folder as the css file

Comment: Most of the answer is okay but why tell OP to change the relative path - if the font is working in other browsers then the path of the fonts must be correct (I only assume it works in other browsers as the question is only about IE8)

Comment: because he is missing one also ./ is incorrect and IE8 is less forgiving than other browsers. plus there is nothing to state that he has even worked on another browser.

Comment: `./` means current directory it's the same as leaving it off altogether

Comment: / <-- current directory

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591240/what-does-dot-slash-refer-to-in-terms-of-an-html-file-path-location

Comment: It's to early in the morning for this peter. My answer allready states if he s linking outside of the tree he should use ../

Comment: the fonts work in other browsers with this  path configuration, but not in IE8. In IE8 will be shown a non configured standard font, if I check the website in IE9 the font will work as wanted

Comment: have you got a link to your site?

Comment: sorry there is no public link, it's an internal project

Comment: what does the console say in IE8 about fontface?

Comment: font not found, by switching to IE9 the font is loaded fine. I know IE8 is not up to date, but the site should support it.

Comment: I tested the code above, nothing new. Font is not shown.

Comment: let me think and ill get back to u going to try something out