# CodeIgniter controllers unreachable

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, xampp

I developed a web application using Xampp and CodeIgniter.  The best way to handle clean routing has been to set the VirtualHost to point on the folder containing the project in xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf, then using routing routes in the route.php file, e.g.,

```
$route['page1'] = "Page1Controller/page1Function";
```

I use href or header like this using root as base folder:

```
href="/page1"
```

All that works very well on locally and I never use `base_url()` or such functions.

Switching to production server, I obviously don't have any rights except for my personal folder and subfolders so when I execute it, root folder becomes root of all domain, not just my project folder.

I tried `base_url()` but it doesn't work, pages aren't found, even when not using `$route`.

Is there a way to handle this without refactoring all links in code or what is the way to do it with refactoring?

**EDIT**

Instead of using `"/page1"`, I'm now using `"./page1"` to access the location of the index.php folder.  However, I'm still not able to access other pages neither with php, nor with html/js.

Comment: can you share also you .htaccess file? By the way the home page works or not?

Comment: make sure the controller name are started with a capital letter, for example "home.php" should be named "Home.php" and leave the `base_url()` blank.

Comment: @Dray I've already done that, thanks.  I'll edit my question

Comment: @TarasBudzyn Yes home page works.  For the .htaccess, I use the standard rewrite rule to get rid of the index.php: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: try using this : `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: @Dray Gives me a 500 :(

Comment: `(o.o)` weird.. I use the same `.htaccess` file

Comment: @Dray thanks for the help, your .htaccess was close.  It finally worked..

Comment: @user3311142 I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming routing is working on local, here are the steps that I took to adapt it to production server.

**1 - First letter capital on Controllers and Views**

CodeIgniter is requesting the use of the capital letters in the naming of Controllers and Views so even if routing is working on Windows, Linux case-sensitivity requires the right naming in both the class title and the reference in the routes.php file.

**2 - Using `'./'` instead of `'/'`**

Because the deployment of the application occurs in a subdomain, the root corresponds to the domain itself rather than the subdomain where index.php resides and which is accessible with `'./'` [(cf. SO question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591240/what-does-dot-slash-refer-to-in-terms-of-an-html-file-path-location).

**3 - Hardcoding subdomain path in the .htaccess file**

Following this [doc](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/urls/remove_index.php.html), I executed steps to correct the standard .htaccess file to make it work with a sub-directory on the server.  The standard variant is simply to remove the `'/'` from this rule :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

which leads to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

However, this hasn't solve it on my server, I had to hardcode the path :

> If you are running EE from a sub-directory and it still doesn’t work
>   after removing the slash, you may need to specify the sub-directory in
>   your rewrite rule. For example, if your sub-folder is named testing,
>   change:
>
> `RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]`
>
> To:
>
> `RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) testing/$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]`
>
> And change:
>
> `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]`
>
> To:
>
> `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ testing/index.php/$1 [L]`