# What is the difference ./ (dot slash) before file path in html and simply just having the file path without it?

Tags: html, filepath

For example what is the difference between ./page.html and page.html?

Comment: I'm not sure why people are voting to close this. OP has done minimal research, but they are clearly not asking to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource**. Personally I think this simple question can be an asset to SO.

Comment: I have voted to reopen this, because this question has been closed for the wrong reason. Its not off-topic at all. In fact, its a duplicate of this high active question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591240/what-does-dot-slash-refer-to-in-terms-of-an-html-file-path-location

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Often the two can be used interchangeably. Both refers the page in current directory

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the path rules it is called a relative path.
./ means current directory, so if you are in a directory called test and you use ./page.html it means the full path is test/page.html.

The second example page.html searches for a page with that name in the current directory.