# Difference between the relative URLs "foo" and "./foo"?

Tags: url, relative-path

When using relative URLs and want to address a file in the same folder we have two options:

- Just type a file name:

  ```
  image1.png
  ```
- Or this:

  ```
  ./image1.png
  ```

I tried these and encountered the same results.

What's the difference between these two? Although the result is the same, is one preferred to another one?

Comment: In short, there's no difference between these two forms. The first option is cleaner since there's an implicit understanding that the file is in the current working directory.

Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591240/what-does-dot-slash-refer-to-in-terms-of-an-html-file-path-location

Answer (score 1):

Essentially: there is none.

Both are relative to "the current context", called the *base URI* in [the specification](https://pretty-rfc.herokuapp.com/RFC3986#base-uri).  (With `./` it's *explicitly* relative to the current context, without it, it's *implicitly* relative to the current context.) With links in both forms, the browser will perform [relative resolution](https://pretty-rfc.herokuapp.com/RFC3986#absolutize) to determine the actual URL to navigate to.

Inclusion of such a prefix is essentially *meaningless noise*, given the implicit behaviour is explicitly documented, and the explicit form is optional.  (It's not *wrong*, it's just not the optimal—most compact—form.)