# When using Grunt to compile Sass I often see a src and dist folder. Where should folders of files that are not compiled go?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, workflow, frontend

With node.js projects using Grunt/Gulp its common to see a src and dist folders. But lets say you are building a static site and have folders of other non-compiled files like fonts and pdfs. Do these go inside dist?

That way you can upload one directory and have all of your production assets. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, there is no real right or wrong answer to your question.

FWIW - I always store fonts and pdfs in the *src* folder and ultimately they get copied to the *dist* folder during my *build* process. One of the benefits of doing that is as you've already mentioned...

> That way you can upload one directory and have all of your production assets.

Another justified reason for copying those assets from *src* to the dist folder is that I typically define [relative paths](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970917/htmlweb.html#h-5.1.2) to other asset in the source code. For example.

---

**html**

```
<img src="./images/icons/logo.gif" alt="logo">
```

---

**css**

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    src: url('../fonts/Lato/Lato-Regular.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/Lato/Lato-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/Lato/Lato-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/Lato/Lato-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'); 
    font-style: normal;
    ...
}
```

By copying all referenced assets and replicating the necessary subfolders of the *src* directory to the *dist* folder, it avoids the need to redefine the asset paths in the distributable code.

For example, take the `@font-face` shown above. If the *fonts* folder and the font files are not copied to the *dist* folder it results in having to redefine the `url` in the distributable `.css` code. *(Either new 'relative' or new 'absolute' paths).*

Whilst there are build tools that can replace the path references I like to consider the *dist* folder as a job bag that includes all the necessary assets independently of the *src* folder.

Again, there is no wright or wrong answer. Consider the pros and cons of either copying the assets *(pdf's and fonts)* to the *dist* folder and choose the approach that best suits your workflow and/or business requirements.

Comment: Hi @RobC thanks for sharing your workflow. I also see some projects with a "src" folder and some without it. I am trying to teach beginners how to follow a best practice so I appreciate your perspective.

Comment: could you please explain what the dot in front of  ./images does? I have seen ../ and ~/ but not that one.

Comment: `./images` means the _images_ folder in the current directory. I.e. The _images_ folder which resides in the same folder as the `.html` file which is making the reference to it. Further info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591240/what-does-dot-slash-refer-to-in-terms-of-an-html-file-path-location#27264246).

Comment: Thank you. Learned something new today : )