# Alternative Relative Path format

Tags: jquery, web

I came across this "././mail/contact_me.php" in a .js file. First I thought this is a syntax error for the relative path "../../mail/contact_me.php". However if I change it to this, the script does not work. Thus I presume "././" does have a meaning. I could not find any discussions on this on the web.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "./" (dot slash) refer to in terms of an HTML file path location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591240/what-does-dot-slash-refer-to-in-terms-of-an-html-file-path-location)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`./` is for the current directory. 
`../` is for the parent directory of the current directory.
Thus `../../` means "go up by two levels in the directory structure".
Instead `././` is probably a typo since it would refer twice to the current directory. This is not an syntax error, but it is redundant. `./mail/contact_me.php` should be equivalent.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Understood.