# Gulp task is not creating css file

Tags: css, sass, gulp

Good morning,

My task created at `gulpfile.js` is following:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function(){
    return gulp.src('sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../assets/css/'));
});
```

when I try to run `gulp sass` I am getting this info:

```
Starting 'sass'...
Finished 'sass' after 20 ms
```

and my css file is not creating (I have obviously created `scss` file before).

What may be the reason of my issue?

Comment: Where is your gulpfile located? Can you please take a screenshot of your folder structure?

Comment: I will send link to my github repo: https://github.com/oltarzewskik/oltarzewskik.github.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the underscore from the name of scss file. Underscores are for partials. Also, `/` is root directory and `./` is for the current directory. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591240/what-does-dot-slash-refer-to-in-terms-of-an-html-file-path-location#answer-27264246)

Update your Gulpfile.js:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  gulp.src('./sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./../assets/css'));
});
```