# i am unable to understand when to use / , ./ and ../ in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am unable to understand the concept and use of '/' ,'./' and '../' in node.js. Help me to understand it in easy way. 
i have a folder fyp in which some files are present and another folder login within that folder and from the files in login folder i want to access file 'welcome.html' of fyp folder by using
`response.sendFile(__dirname + 'welcome.html')`. but i don't know how to access this file and it is showing error.

`app.get('/', function(request, response) 
{ response.sendFile(__dirname + 'welcome.html'); });`

Comment: Welcome! Those terms are usually referencing file directory navigation. This has some good write up on that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591240/what-does-dot-slash-refer-to-in-terms-of-an-html-file-path-location . app.get('/', ...) is making a network call to '/' where the host is wherever the service is running. So if you are running locally, it will try and call http://localhost:<port>/ . If you were on a server it might try something like https://serverHostName:<port>/. Where the slash on the end is that slash in the app.get('/')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your case you are just concatenating two strings: one from `__dirname` and one `'welcome.html'` defined by you.

you can use `path.join([...paths])` from 'path' nodejs module to work with relative paths. 
read more [here](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths)