# Why cant my file load the script that implemented in a separate css file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, handlebars.js

So this is my layout for most of my pages:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    </head>
```

my css is in a different folder , and some of the css for certain page such like my home looks something like :

```
.home-banner {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(home-banner6.jpg);
  height: 170px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Do i just put it like that in .css?
Heres an image of my directory as well.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gtHb.png)

Comment: when you point the url: `home-banner6.jpg` it means that the image is on the same place where the css is.

Comment: sorry i meant " .home-banner  {...} i put that in a separate file called style.css in a folder call css. so when i do href= /css/style.css will it render the style?

Comment: `/css/style.css` this means: "go to root and then enter css folder and execute the file style.css " i'm sorry but i can't understand what is the exact question here (maybe it's my English).

Comment: No,no, maybe it’s how I worded the question but basically in my  home.handle bars I made some style and I added those style to a file called style.css. However, the style isn’t rendering .

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591240/what-does-dot-slash-refer-to-in-terms-of-an-html-file-path-location